# Dynamically change error messages in Kendo UI validator?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-validator

think I have a 2 text fields. Can I change there error messages according to text fields.

Here is a example.

1st text box is a email field and it is required field.
So I keep it a error messages in a array :

```
["this field is required", "enter a valid e mail"]
```

2 text box is required field.
Its error message :

```
["enter a valid value in the field"]
```

but in kendo ui validator like this ...

```
  var validator = $("#formID").kendoValidator( 
       { messages : {
                     required : "this field is required",
                     email : "enter a valid email address"
       }
       }).data("kendoValidator");
```

How I change these values dynamically according to the text fields error messages??

Answer (score 7):

you can create `function` for both `required` and `email` to **customize error messages according to html input fields.**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input name="username" required /> <br />
    <input type="email" name="userEmail" required data-message="My custom email message" /> <br />
    <button>Validate</button>
</form>
```

**Script section:**

```
<script>
     $("#myform").kendoValidator({
             messages: {
                 // defines a message for the 'custom' validation rule
                 custom: "Please enter valid value for my custom rule",

                 // overrides the built-in message for the required rule
                 required: function(input) {
                     return getRequiredMessage(input);
                 },

                 // overrides the built-in message for the email rule
                 // with a custom function that returns the actual message
                 email: function(input) {
                     return getMessage(input);
                 }
             },
             rules: {
               custom: function(input) {
                 if (input.is("[name=username]")) {
                     return input.val() === "Tom";
                 }
                 return true;
               }
             }
        });

        function getMessage(input) {
          return input.data("message");
        }
        function getRequiredMessage(input) {
           if (input.is("[name=username]")) {
                     return "User name is required";
                 }
            else
                 return input.attr("name") + " Field is Required";
        }
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manirajss/kcwcyc0p/1/)

Here in `getRequiredMessage` function i customized error message based on input name.

I provided  "User name is required" for input username. you can provide the error message even from array if you wish.